# Asking (good) questions that you know will not get answered

Tags: discussion, questions

It seems like there are no experts for the PnP "The dark Eye" on this site (As the tag had to be created when I was posting my question, and no one could give me an answer).

Is it okay if I post more questions about TDE, even though I know I will most likely not get an answer here, as long as these questions have a good quality?

Comment: Just as a thought: TDE (née *Das Schwarze Auge*) is a German-language game, and is most popular in Europe. There's an English translation, but it's not very well known in the US. As an English-language site, I'm not surprised there are few experts on the game here.

Comment: @Jadasc Yeah, I'm german myself, that's why I was not surprised to not get an answer here. Still, sometimes you find people playing it outside of Europe, and asking questions about it can only promote it (I had never heard of most of the PnPs that are talked about here, safe for DnD and Shadowrun). ;-)

Comment: @malexmave Maybe you could link to your question on some forum for DSA?

Comment: @C.Ross I'm currently not active in any such forum, and most of them will probably not like it too much if I just link questions instead of asking them there... Plus, they would most likely be german forums.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Sure.

Posting good questions can only attract the kinds of experts you're seeking.

Comment: It would probably help if some of the grognards shared the question around... :-)

Comment: SEs get good search engine rank as well, so your questions will (pretty soon) be ranked well in Google and perhaps draw answers.